# rank of formal derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field, $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and $K[x]_{ \leq n} $ he space of polynomials above $K$, that have a maximum degree of $n$.
We define the formal derivation as follow:

$\frac{d}{dx}= K[x]_{ \leq n} \rightarrow K[x]_{ \leq n} $

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k \longmapsto \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot a_kx^{k-1} $

Determine the rank of $\frac{d}{dx}$.

I would say that the rank  is $n$, because $rank(f)=dim(Im(f))$ and polynomials of different degrees are linearly independent.

Comment: There are n elements in this set { 1,x,...,x^{n-1} }

Comment: @fear, use a basis of $K_n[x]$. Moreover, beware to the case when the characteristic of $K$ is $\leq n$.

Comment: A basis of $K[x]_n$ would be $\{x^n, x^{n-1},...x,1\}$ with $n+1$ elements. After derivation i've got $\{nx^{n-1},...,2x,1\}$, so $n-1$ elements.